# How to filter a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query :

```
   WITH supervisors AS
    (
            --Query that returns all of the supervisors in a department 
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                sm.fk_manager AS id_supervisor,
                supervisor_manager.fk_manager AS id_supervisor_manager,
                s.email,
                s.fk_branch,
                s.fk_department
            FROM global.staff_managers sm

            INNER JOIN global.staff s
            ON s.id_staff = sm.fk_manager

            INNER JOIN global.staff_managers supervisor_manager
            ON supervisor_manager.fk_staff = sm.fk_manager

            WHERE s.fk_branch = 1 AND fk_department = 18

    )
    SELECT * FROM supervisors
    -- It sometimes happens that a department has many supervisors,
    --but one or many of these are the supervisors of the rest of the supervisors as well
    --and these are the people we want to show, so we get rid of those supervisors whose superior
    --is in the list of supervisors of that department
    WHERE id_supervisor_manager NOT IN (SELECT id_supervisor FROM supervisors)
```

Which returns the principal supervisor/s of a department in a company

I would like to have a query which returns these supervisors without the need to indicate a department

I first tried  counting the number of times a supervisor appeared as manager of supervisors for a specific branch and then selecting that supervisor who was in charge of more supervisors in his department, however it didn't work as there were supervisors who were in charge of other supervisors who also were in charge of other supervisors, thus putting a subordinate at the same level as his superior

Sample information : 
[image]

Supervisors of a specific department (sample 1): 
[image]

Supervisor I recieve in the current stored procedure as he is the superior of the rest of the supervisors in the department (sample 1) :
[image]

Supervisors in other department sample(2) :
[image]

Supervisor that needs to be retrieved : 
[image]

The desired result :
[image]

I would really appreciate if someone helps me find a way to return the top supervisors of an specific branch

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I just edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: Please don't post images.

Comment: how to post tables? When i copy them from excel they are converted to images automatically

Answer (score 0):

To get all principal departments' supervisors means to return all managers whose heads have another department id. Am I right?

```
select distinct emp.fk_staff id_supervisor, emp.fk_manager id_supervisor_manager,
dep_emp.fk_branch, dep_emp.fk_department, dep_emp.email
from global.staff_managers emp 
inner join global.staff dep_emp on dep_emp.id_staff=emp.fk_staff
inner join global.staff dep_man on dep_man.id_staff=emp.fk_manager
where dep_man.fk_department != dep_emp.fk_department
and dep_emp.fk_branch = 1
```